# Проблема с поиском по массиву

Tags: python, массивы, поиск

Имеется простенькая задача (см. комментарии) по поиску в произвольном массиве, однако поиск осуществляется некорректно (выводит неправильное количество). В чем может быть проблема, голову сломал:

```
mass=[input('Введите через запятую буквенные элементы массива:\n').split(',')]

#количество слов начинающихся на А
count=0
for i in mass:
    if i[0]=='А' or i[0]=='а'or i[0]=='a' or i[0]=='A':
        count+=1        
print(count)

#количество слов с четной длиной
coun=0
for i in mass:
    if len(i)%2==0:
        coun+=1
print(coun)

#слова, состоящие из трех символов
for i in mass:
    if len(i)==3:
        print(i)
```

Comment: `mass` у Вас будет массив с одним елементом - массивом, уберите `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправленная версия вашего кода:

```
mass=input('Введите через запятую буквенные элементы массива:\n').split(',')

# количество слов, начинающихся на А
count = 0
for i in mass:
    if i[0] in 'aAаА':
        count += 1        
print(count)

# количество слов с четной длиной
coun = 0
for i in mass:
    if len(i)%2 == 0:
        coun += 1
print(coun)

# слова, состоящие из трех символов
for i in mass:
    if len(i) == 3:
        print(i)
```

Сокращённое решение:

```py
mass=input('Введите через запятую буквенные элементы массива:\n').split(',')

# количество слов, начинающихся на А
print(len([word for word in mass if word[0] in 'aAаА']))

# количество слов с четной длиной
print(len([word for word in mass if not len(word)%2]))

# слова, состоящие из трех символов
print(', '.join(word for word in mass if len(word) == 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить одну строчку с ифом: `if 'A' in i or 'a' in i:`
При переборе i принимает значение слова, а слово-это список. Простоя проверка на вхождение элемента

```
mass = input('Введите через запятую буквенные элементы массива:\n').split(',') # количество слов начинающихся на А 

count = 0 
for i in mass: 
    if 'A' in i or 'a' in i: 
        count += 1 
        print(count) # количество слов с четной длиной 

coun = 0 
for i in mass: 
    if len(i) % 2 == 0: 
        coun += 1 
        print(coun) # слова, состоящие из трех символов 

for i in mass: 
    if len(i) == 3: 
        print(i)
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что первое условие `#количество слов начинающихся на А`